# Trust or entrusted thing

Tags: vocabulary

If someone puts something into someone's care or protection that has to be given back the same later, will this thing be called 'a trust' or do we necessarily have to call it 'an entrusted thing'?

> You must give the trust back as same as it was at the time of giving in your care.

I mean can we use the word 'trust' as a noun for a thing put in someone's care or protection? Is that understandable?

Comment: There is a legal concept of "a trust", i.e., entrusted property or monies, but  the usage given is *not* correct formal or colloquial English. Look look up synonyms, e.g., "consignment", "commission," or just "property," in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "trust" (countable noun) is a specific legal arrangement where money or property is given to someone else in the future, and it is held by a third party until that future time. For example, a rich grandparent might leave a million dollars for their grandchild in a trust at a bank that the grandchild can only access when they turn 25, theoretically long after the grandparent has died.

If you give something valuable to someone "in trust" (uncountable noun), it means that person holds it for you with the understanding that it's still yours and you will have it back later. Like if I have a valuable collection of coins, but I'm moving out of the country and don't want to bring it with me, I might leave it in my best friend's basement "in trust". It means it's still completely mine, under my control, and my friend isn't borrowing it for their own purposes.

In this second situation, I could talk about "*my coin collection, which I have entrusted to my best friend*".

It's correct grammar but unnatural to talk about "*my entrusted coin collection*"